# Why do (deamon) threads in Python behave that way when using process pools?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, daemon

Given the following code I would expect the code to run for around 6 seconds as I would expect the calls with argument 0 to terminate almost instantly and the calls with argument 100 to timeout after 3 seconds.

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time
import multiprocessing


def timeout_function_wrapper(function, args, timeout):
    # Wrapper function to allow for proper results etc.
    def auxiliary(n, out_q):
        res = function(n)
        out_q.put(res)  # to get result back from thread target

    result_q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=auxiliary, args=(args, result_q))
    thread.start()
    thread.join(timeout=timeout)  # if it times out, thread.is_alive() will be True, no exception is raised

    if thread.is_alive():
        raise multiprocessing.TimeoutError("Timed out after waiting for {}s".format(timeout))
    return result_q.get()

def foo(t):
    time.sleep(t)
    return t*t

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1, maxtasksperchild=1) as pool:
        futures = [pool.apply_async(timeout_function_wrapper, [foo, i, 3]) for i in [100, 0, 100,0]]

        for i, x in enumerate(futures):
            try:
                res = x.get()  # timeout not needed here, it's in the wrapper
                print("Res", i, res)
            except multiprocessing.TimeoutError as e:
                print("Timeout")

    print("Took {}".format(time.time() - t1))
```

It turns out that this code runs for around 103 seconds. Why is that the case? If I change the the line

`thread = threading.Thread(target=auxiliary, args=(args, result_q))`

to

`thread = threading.Thread(target=auxiliary, args=(args, result_q), daemon=True)`

it finishes in 6 seconds.

**Questions**

Why do threads need to be daemon threads to timeout "in the intended way"?
Why does it timeout "correctly" once and not at all once when they are not daemon threads?

**UPDATE**
So in addition I found that if foo is replaced by:

```
def foo(t):
    while True:
        pass
    return 42
```

The whole program does not terminate (even after the sum of timeouts) regardless of it being daemon threads or not.

Comment: from the docs: ["A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects). Basically even though you `raise` an error, there was no error in the thread so it doesn't exit right away and the main process catches the error in order to send it back to the main process. If there are still non-daemonic threads sitting around, the process won't exit.

Comment: Reply to the other comment: Making foo non-terminating (i.e. writing while True: pass instead of time.sleep) makes the whole program non terminating regardless of it being a daemon or not. Why is that? shouldn't the thread and therefore process be terminated after the timeout is reached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to elaborate on Aaron's comment:

First of all, without *daemon=True* your code as posted (plus the missing import statements) will actually takes a little more than 200 seconds.

The issue is that for each submitted task, since you specified *maxtasksperchild=1* in addition to *processes=1* when initializing your multiprocessing pool, the pool manager must start a new process but it first waits for the old process to complete. This will not occur until the thread it started to run the `auxiliary` function completes because it is not a daemon thread. If you specify the thread to be a daemon thread, then it will terminate right away as soon as the main thread for the pool process terminates. This is what you observed.

You can instead remove the *maxtasksperchild=1* argument so that it no longer becomes necessary to wait for the pool process to finish just to restart another process to run the next submitted task. So the same pool process can now start multiple non-daemon threads without blocking. When you exit the `with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1) as pool:` block, there is an implicit call to `pool.terminate` that immediately terminates all the processes in your pool (which is only 1 in your case) regardless of whether it has any non-daemon threads running in addition the the main thread. Consequently the running time is the 6 seconds you expect. If you instead of using a context manager for the pool, which calls `terminate` on exit you use the following code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = time.time()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    futures = [pool.apply_async(timeout_function_wrapper, [foo, i, 3]) for i in [100, 0, 100,0]]

    for i, x in enumerate(futures):
        try:
            res = x.get()  # timeout not needed here, it's in the wrapper
            print("Res", i, res)
        except multiprocessing.TimeoutError as e:
            print("Timeout")
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print("Took {}".format(time.time() - t1))
```

You will then get your 4 results back right away, unlike in the situation where you specified *maxtasksperchild=1*, but the program will not reach the `print` statement until the threads created by the pool process terminates allowing the pool process itself to terminate. Since these threads are running in parallel, the total time will be 103 seconds rather than 203 seconds.

Comment: Making foo non-terminating (i.e. writing while True: pass instead of time.sleep) makes the whole program non terminating regardless of it being a daemon or not. Why is that? shouldn't the thread and therefore process be terminated after the timeout is reached?

Comment: If you are referring to your posted code, your assertion is false, i.e. making the thread a daemon thread does result in the program terminating. If you are referring to your code modified by my change above, again your program will terminate if you use daemon threads. If you are talking about something else, then please clarify.

Comment: By the way, when you issue `thread.join(timeout=timeout)`, it does not result in in the thread automatically terminating after `timeout` seconds; the meaning is to wait for the thread to terminate but no longer than `timeout` seconds. That is why you then test to see if the thread is still alive.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to kill it before raising the TimeoutError?

Comment: I have an odd problem where I honestly currently dont know how to produce a minimal working example. But in short when foo is a function running an algorithm of mine then the process kind of get stuck. While wen foo is "just" a time.sleep(1000) the timeout works as intended.

Comment: Although you can kill/terminate a child process by calling `terminate` or `kill` on the `Process` instance, you are dealing here with a *submitted task* being run by a pool process that you want to terminate -- not the process itself. All you can do is call `pool.terminate()`, but this will kill all pool processes stopping any tasks that have been submitted but not yet completed.

Comment: I think I was able to find something. So I get "weird" (I may amend my post when I have time to specify weird) different behavior when foo returns ints and when foo returns other data. Note I have started to use multiprocessing.Queue instead of queue.Queue. I was not able to find exactly what kind of data causes problems but it seems to be at least dictionaries containing numpy arrays.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you had been using a `queue.Queue`, which is not meant for passing to a child process. Whatever you place on a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance must be serializable with `pickle`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247822/discussion-between-julian-and-booboo).